# Controller URL Issue in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Something went wrong while routing in MVC. My URL now displays like:

> localhost:4578//name/S(weu2uyteuig2yu32g)

I dont know why `S(weu2uyteuig2yu32g)` is coming at the end of the URL.

Comment: Please post your routing configuration, and also one of your views where you generate this link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have something like this in your web.config?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true"
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In asp.net, if you choose a cookieless environment the system will create the session key in the url.

Haven't checked the exact syntax for MVC, but I would expect it to be something similar.

Comment: Yes, your answer is right. After removing this regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Once I meet this situation. but now don't remember why. May be you work with **MD5 Hash** and **call your method wrong**. If not you should type all details.

Comment: This should be a comment at most. MVC doesn't automagically add characters to your URLs if you "work with MD5 and call it wrong".